# python object Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html

In my following html

```
<script> var scr_obj = {{obj}} </script>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-xs" id="v_u_button" style="float:right;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="view_script">View</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="update_script">Update</button>
</div>
```

the `{{obj}}` is a python object which looks something like this

`<script> var scr_obj = <app.database.models.TestObject object at 0x7fafab336048> </script>`
This is throwing off an error in my chrome console as `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

And i need the entire object in that variable "scr_obj" so i can use it in my JS to talk to my flask backend for execution of other tasks on my device.How can i by pass this?

Thanks

Comment: You can't put a `<script>` tag inside another `<script>` tag.

Comment: What is inside the script tag when you inspect the html?

Comment: hi whackamadoodle3000 inside the script tag is `{{obj}}` which during runtime holds a db object `<app.database.models.TestObject object at 0x7fafab336048>`. I am trying to see if there is a way to utilize the db object rather than querying the db again

Answer (score 0):

You need `<app.database.models.TestObject object at 0x7fafab336048>` to be in quotes. If it isn't, then it will not be registered as a string. The `<` sign in javascript means less than. This is why it is getting a Syntax Error.

Comment: So thats a db object i tired JSON stringifying it but doesnt work still getting the same error